# How many points can we remove from $\mathbb{Q}$ so it is still dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I want to check whether:

> - $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}$ is dense (or not) in $\mathbb{R}$
> - $\mathbb{Q}\backslash F$, $F$ is a finite set in $\mathbb{Q}$, is dense (or not) in$\mathbb{R}$
> - $\mathbb{Q}\backslash X$, $X$ is an infinite set in $\mathbb{Q}$ is
>   dense (or not) in $\mathbb{R}$

But I think this problem is resisting my most direct approach:

> We know that a set $D$ is dense if $\overline D = X$, where $X$ is the entire space containing $D$
>
> Then we wish to know whether $\overline {\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}} = \mathbb{R}$
>
> My approach is that $\overline {\mathbb{Q}\backslash\{0\}} = \overline {\mathbb{Q}\cap\{0\}^c} = \overline {\mathbb{Q}\cap \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}}$  = (does this work?) = $\overline {\mathbb{Q}}\cap \overline  {\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}}$

But then this turns into a question whether $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Can anyone show me how this can be done?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Thank you for sharing your previous work and for formatting it so well.  I don't think that a "formulaic" approach works in this case. Rather, try to show that $\mathbb{Q} \setminus  \{0\}$ is indeed dense in $\mathbb{R}$ directly from the definition. This will also give you insights regarding the second question. As to the last question, note that $\mathbb{Q}$ itself is infinite. So what happens if you take $F = \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Can you find a sequence of elements in $\mathbb{Q}$ that converge to $0$?

Comment: We can remove an a lot of points from $\mathbb{Q}$. For example, the decimal fractions, that is, numbers of the form $\frac{a}{10^n}$, where $n$ ranges over the non-negative integers, and $a$ ranges over the integers, is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Any thoughts, at least about your first item, or about how to relate the first item to the second?  For the third item, there are no blanket guarantees since removing $\mathbb{Q}$ is going to leave the non-dense empty set, but there are infinite subsets like $\mathbb{Z}$ whose removal does not affect the density of what remains.

Comment: @hardmath Hello I made a mistake, it should say that the finite set or the infinite set is in $\Bbb{Q}$. I see now that $\mathbb{Q} \backslash \{0\}$ is going to be dense, because $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, so it doesn't matter if we remove it, I'm not sure if the logic applies going forwrad

Comment: Well, I understood you could not remove points from $\mathbb{Q}$ that were not in $\mathbb{Q}$ to begin with.  However $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @EricY - think about your last comment again. the closure of the empty set is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can remove countably many points, since the set of dyadic rationals $\mathbb{Q}_d$, which are rational numbers of the form $$\frac{k}{2^n}, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N},$$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but clearly $\mathbb{Q}-\mathbb{Q}_d$ is also countably infinite and dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

This follows (somewhat indirectly) from the Archimedean property of the real numbers.

Comment: This is true, but you have to be careful with the quantifiers: *there exist* countably many points we can remove which leave $\mathbb{Q}$ dense, but *there also exist* countably many points we can remove which **don't** leave $\mathbb{Q}$ dense (namely, we could take away all of them - $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable!). This contrasts with e.g. the finite case, where *no matter which* finitely many points you remove, $\mathbb{Q}$ stays countable.

Comment: I agree; I meant for it to be read "we can remove countably many points in the sense that there exists a countably infinite subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that ...". Anyone reading my answer should take note of Noah's comment, because the stronger statement "we can remove countably many points in the sense that any countably infinite subset" is NOT true, as Noah gives an example.

Comment: Yes - the "you" there meant the OP, not you. :P